# running ggplotly function resuts to Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Today I was trying to run code which previously worked fine. But I got following error:

```
> p1 <- ggplot(dframe, aes(x, y, text=sprintf("letter: %s<br>LETTER: %s<br>", a, b))) + geom_line() + geom_point()
> ggplotly(p1)
We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
seq <- 1:10
name <- c(paste0("company",1:10))
value <- c(250,125,50,40,40,30,20,20,10,10)
lett <-  letters[1:10]
dframe <- data.frame(seq,name,value,lett)
```

My environment:

- "R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)"
- ggplot2 2.2.1
- plotly  4.7.1

why this happens? Thanks

Comment: Try using `label` instead of `text`

Comment: I've tried with `text`, `label` and `key` all worked in the past, but now all return same error.

Comment: did you map the `x` and `y` to `dframe` variables?

Comment: oh, such a stupid mistake, thank you very much. I had to somehow screw datasets, please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the creation of `p1` you're trying to use the variable name `x` as the x axis. The error is telling you that it can't find the object `x` in your data frame. Indeed, when you're creating `dframe`, you're not naming any column as `x`, so that is to be expected.